# Sticking a soft body to a moving surface

Tags: animation, soft-body

So I'm fairly new to blender and still learning the essentials.

Is there any way to stick a soft body to a moving surface? The portion of my project I'm stuck on has a rotating disk that the soft body is supposed to land on then move down an assembly line. But currently the soft body crushes upon impact and flies off because of the motion. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If the model collapses you need to increase the *[X] Edges > Bending* value and try *[X] Stiffness* in the *Physics Properties > Softbody* section.

At the beginning of the *Softbody* settings, you will also find *[Object > Friction](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/physics/soft_body/settings/object.html)* and *Object > Mass*. They influence the inertia of the object and whether the object has enough grip and is moved along or slides on the spot. But the *Friction* also slows down/damps the fall.

There is also a *Softbody & Cloth > Friction* value in the *Collision* settings for the plane. It works well in *Cloth* simulations but I could not see any effects in my *Softbody* example. The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/physics/collision.html) only mentions *cloth* for this *Friction* value.

Last but not least, you can use a *Force Field* with a negative strength to attract the object and hold it in place.

The settings depend on the size and geometry of your model, the height of the fall, and on the rotation speed.

Example with the default cube:

[image: example animation]

The *Forcefield* is parented to the plane. There are keyframes for the strength (-5) of the forcefield so it is activated at frame 40 when the cube hits the plane. (Otherwise, it would immediately attract and crush the cube.)

The cube is 2 times subdivided. *Softbody > Object > Friction* is 1.0 and *Mass* is 0.5 kg. The value of *Bending* is 2.5. The plane rotates 1200° over 250 frames.